# wordpress Facebook Comments not loading

Tags: facebook, wordpress, comments

I installed Facebook Comments for WordPress version 1.5.2 with my WordPress. However it doesn't show any comments from Facebook, always showing loading text. I verified the problem exists in both Firefox and Internet Explorer.

My WordPress link: http://184.106.131.16/wordpress/?p=293

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You might like my Simple Facebook Comments For Wordpress wordpress plugin I recently released. It makes the whole process of adding facebook connect comments to your wordpress site super easy and fast.

http://www.davidswordpressplugins.com/simple-facebook-comments-for-wordpress/